# sam build is stuck in NpmInstall when oracledb-for-lambda is included in package.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am using AWS SAM and Node.js. When I run "sam build, it is always stuck in NpmInstall. I noticed that this only happens when I added the oracledbdb-for-lambda package. I tried it with express and other npm packages and it works.